# Python overriding getter without setter

Tags: python, oop, properties, setter, getter

```
class human(object):
    def __init__(self, name=''):
        self.name = name

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        self._name = value

class superhuman(human):
    @property
    def name(self):
        return 'super ' + name

s = superhuman('john')
print s.name

# Doesn't work :( "AttributeError: can't set attribute"
s.name = 'jack'
print s.name
```

I want to be able to override the property but be able to use the super parent's setter without having to override the setter in the child class.

Is that pythonicaly possible?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use *just* the `.getter` decorator of the original property:

```
class superhuman(human):
    @human.name.getter
    def name(self):
        return 'super ' + self._name
```

Note that you have to use the full name to reach the original property descriptor on the parent class.

Demonstration:

```
>>> class superhuman(human):
...     @human.name.getter
...     def name(self):
...         return 'super ' + self._name
... 
>>> s = superhuman('john')
>>> print s.name
super john
>>> s.name = 'jack'
>>> print s.name
super jack
```

The `property` descriptor object is just *one* object, even though it can have multiple methods associated with it (the getter, setter and deleter). The `.getter`, `.setter` and `.deleter` decorator functions provided by an existing `property` descriptor return a copy of the descriptor itself, with that one specific method replaced.

So in your `human` base class what happens is that you first *create* the descriptor with the `@property` decorator, then replace that descriptor with one that has both a getter and a setter with the `@name.setter` syntax. That works because python decorators replace the original decorated function with the same name, it basically executes `name = name.setter(name)`. See [How does the @property decorator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work) for the details on how that all works.

In your subclass you simply use that trick to create a new copy of the descriptor with just the getter replaced.