# why do you need "if instance is None" in __get__ of a descriptor class?

Tags: python, descriptor, python-descriptors

I get the following example from Effective Python item 31:

```
from weakref import WeakKeyDictionary
class Grade(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._values = WeakKeyDictionary()
    def __get__(self, instance, instance_type):
        if instance is None: return self
        return self._values.get(instance, 0)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if not (0 <= value <= 100):
            raise ValueError('Grade must be between 0 and 100')
        self._values[instance] = value


# Example 16
class Exam(object):
    math_grade = Grade()
    writing_grade = Grade()
    science_grade = Grade()

first_exam = Exam()
first_exam.writing_grade = 82
second_exam = Exam()
second_exam.writing_grade = 75
print('First ', first_exam.writing_grade, 'is right')
print('Second', second_exam.writing_grade, 'is right')
```

I can't think of any reason to have `if instance is None: return self` in `__get__`. How can an `Exam` (or other potential classes using `Grade`) instance be `None`?

Comment: `Exam.math_grade` will pass `None` as instance to `__get__`. There's no instance involved in that case.

Comment: might be helpful http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/ChrisBeaumont/5758381/descriptor_writeup.ipynb

Comment: Please don't add follow-up questions into your question - if you have another question, ask it! You can always include a link back to this one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python will pass in `None` for the instance when accessing the descriptor on the class.

By returning `self` in that case you can access the descriptor object on the class without having to bypass the protocol (by accessing `ClassObj.__dict__['name_of_descriptor']`).

```
>>> class DemoDescriptor:
...     def __get__(self, instance, type_):
...         if instance is None:
...             print('Accessing descriptor on the class')
...             return self
...         print('Accessing descriptor on the instance')
...         return 'Descriptor value for instance {!r}'.format(instance)
... 
>>> class DemoClass(object):
...     foo = DemoDescriptor()
... 
>>> DemoClass.foo  # on the class
Accessing descriptor on the class
<__main__.DemoDescriptor object at 0x1041d3c50>
>>> DemoClass.__dict__['foo']  # bypassing the descriptor protocol
<__main__.DemoDescriptor object at 0x1041d3c50>
>>> DemoClass().foo  # on the instance
Accessing descriptor on the instance
'Descriptor value for instance <__main__.DemoClass object at 0x1041d3438>'
```

This is how the `__get__` method implementations for `function` and `property` objects work too.

For your specific case, each of `Exam.math_grade`, `Exam.writing_grade` or `Exam.science_grade` will call `Grade.__get__`, passing in `None` for the instance, and `Exam` for the `instance_type`.

Comment: what about `__set__`? will `Exam.math_grade=3` pass `None` to `instance` argument too? Is there any use case of accessing the descriptor object by returning `self`?

Comment: @RNA: descriptors only support *setting* on instances. Assigning to `Exam.math_grade` would replace the descriptor object with whatever the right-hand-side produces.

Comment: that seems not true (?). let me update the question.

Comment: @RNA: The `@property` descriptor object heavily relies on `self` being returned, as otherwise you couldn't use the object in sub-classes to override a property setter or getter or deleter.

Comment: @RNA: Perhaps you made a mistake in your test; it very much is true, see https://gist.github.com/mjpieters/531cb4d657d0b38b8684

Comment: I got what you mean by "replacing the descriptor object". but still have problem understanding "The `@property` descriptor object heavily relies on self being returned"... could you give an example why it is good to return `self`?

Comment: @RNA: `ClassObject.descriptorname` returns whatever `ClassObject.__dict__['descriptorname'].__get__(None, ClassObject)` returns. Returning something other than `self` would give you whatever you returned instead. That's inconvenient if you need to use the descriptor object itself repeatedly.

Comment: @RNA: see [Python overriding getter without setter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15786149) for an example where a `property` descriptor is accessed; `human.name` is a property descriptor object, and that invokes `human.__dict__['name'].__get__(None, human)`.