# Use of property's getter in python

Tags: python, properties, getter-setter

i was looking into properties and could not understand the use of getter.

Code :

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,p):
        self._p = p
    @property
    def p(self):
        return self._p
    @p.setter
    def p(self, value):
        self._p = value
    @p.getter
    def p(self):
        return self._p
```

so,i did the following

```
obj = A(10)
print(obj.p)
```

i got the following output:

> 10

So, i thought, @p.getter is called and the value of _q is returned.

But, i tried without @p.getter as below

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,p):
        self._p = p
    @property
    def p(self):
        return self._p
    @p.setter
    def p(self, value):
        self._p = value
```

And did the following

```
obj = A(10)
print(obj.p)
```

and even then i got the following output:

> 10

So, i was wondering, what is the actual use of @p.getter here, when @property it self was able to give us the value of _q

Comment: Closely related: [Python overriding getter without setter](//stackoverflow.com/q/15785982).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@property` decorator on a function creates a new `property` object and sets the decorated function as the getter. So within *the same class*, the `@p.getter` decorator is not very useful, no.

However, the decorator is *very* useful if you wanted to override the getter in a subclass, or a reuse just the setter of the property on, but on a different class altogether:

```
class Foo(object):
    @property
    def p(self):
        return self._p

    @p.setter
    def p(self, value):
        self._p = value

class Bar(Foo):
    @Foo.p.getter
    def p(self):
        return self._p + 10
```

or by copying the property object across to a different class:

```
class NotASubclass(object):
    @Foo.p.getter
    def p(self):
        return self._p * 10
```

Now `Bar()`and `NotASubclass` have a different getter for their property `p`, but both reuse the setter defined on the property for `Foo()`.

In both cases the `@p.getter` decorator creates a new `property` instance to store as an attribute of the class object, but their `fset` attributes all point to the same, single function object that acts as the setter.  This is why it is enough to just reference `@Foo.p.getter` in either case; you only need the single `property` instance in the class namespace.

Also see [How does the @property decorator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work) and [Python overriding getter without setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15785982/python-overriding-getter-without-setter)

Comment: Thanks, second  example is great

Comment: property by default return themselves because in the actual implementation `def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        if self.fget is None:
            raise AttributeError("unreadable attribute")
        return self.fget(obj)` , if the getter is not defined, it return's itself.Because of that i was able to get the value of _p Am i right?

Comment: @InAFlash: no, if the getter is not defined, an `AttributeError` exception is raised. `obj` is the instance to which to bind, if that's `None` the access was on the class. So `ClassObj.property_name` gives you the property object itself (because the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) then calls `ClassObj.__dict__['property_name'].__get__(None, ClassObj)`), and `instance.property_name` gives you the result of the getter function (because then  `ClassObj.__dict__['property_name'].__get__(instance, ClassObj)`)` is called).

Answer (score 4):

The `@property.getter` decorator can be useful if you want to override a getter from a parent class in a subclass. It allows you to easily "copy" a property from the parent class and override only the getter, keeping the setter and deleter intact.

Example:

```
class Parent:
    @property
    def p(self):
        return 'parent'

    @p.setter
    def p(self, value):
        print('setting p to', value)

    @p.deleter
    def p(self):
        print('deleting p')

class Child(Parent):
    @Parent.p.getter
    def p(self):
        return 'child'

print(Parent().p)  # output: parent
print(Child().p)   # output: child
Child().p = 3      # output: setting p to 3
del Child().p      # output: deleting p
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've noticed, in this case, it's totally useless since you already passed the getter here

```
@property
def p(self):
    return self._p
```

but it might be useful for a couple corner cases at least, like dynamically redefining the getter for an existing property. I have to say I never had such a use case actually but well...

Comment: so, p.getter is not used often? is that what you are saying?

Comment: @InAFlash cf Aran-Fey's answer which is much better than mine